# Refreshing views by redirect back while preserving scroll location in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, redirect, page-refresh

I'm building an Instagram-like app in rails. You can submit a post, vote on posts (via act_as_votable) and  comment on others' posts.

My issue comes when the user votes or adds a comment to a post. I'd like those changes to be reflected in the views instantly with something simple  (i.e. without using Ajax).

Currently I'm reflecting the changes by using redirect_to forcing a reload

```
#as an example here an upvote action in my posts controller

  def upvote
      @post.vote_by voter: current_user, duplicate: true
      flash[:info] = "Your vote has been recorded"
      redirect_to posts_path
  end
```

Although this works, the scroll bar jumps to the top of the page after each reload making it a nightmare for the user to scroll back down to the position he was every time he votes or add a comment.

I've tried many things so far to try to preserve the scroll location after reload without success, among those:

1)After I noticed that a browser reload preserves the scroll location, I tried to implement a simple JS solution by adding a click event listener that reloads the page with the code below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.class_of_link_tag').click(function() {
      window.location.reload(true);
  });
});
```

This maintains the scroll position if applied to any div but for some reason when there's a link_to tag involved the click is not listened and the page doesn't get reloaded.

2)Tried to implement 'Scroll Sneak' (http://mrcoles.com/blog/scroll-sneak-maintain-position-between-page-loads/). In a very weird way it worked at first and at some point stopped working. It's been impossible to pinpoint why. I've basically included the JS source (http://mrcoles.com/media/js/scroll-sneak.js) in application.js and appended this script at the bottom of body.

```
  (function() {
      var sneaky = new ScrollSneak(location.hostname), posts = document.getElementsByClassName('vote-icon'), i = 0, len = posts.length;
      for (; i < len; i++) {
          posts[i].onclick = sneaky.sneak;
      }
  })();
```

'vote-icon' is the class of the div containing the link to the 'posts#upvote'

```
  <!--a portion of the posts index.html.erb -->
    <div class="vote-icon">
      <%= link_to vote_path(post_id: post.id), method: :put do %>
      <%= image_tag("vote.png", :height => 45)  %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
```

I'm getting to a point of desperation here! Could you give me some guidance on how could I solve this? Is it possible to use window.location.reload in a link so it invokes the controller action and reloads the browser via JS subsequently? How could I approach this issue to get the best UX without using Ajax?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

AJAX isn't as scary as it sounds.

The only way to do it without using AJAX, while still updating the votes in real time for other users would be to make each of the landmarks on your page (images, in the case) a unique anchor tag, which you can then include in the redirect url.

for example if your /page is set up like

img1

img2

img3

img4

and let's assume each image takes up a whole viewport height, so you can only see one at a time. When I click to vote on img3, if it's wrapped in an anchor tag

`<a href='#img3'> <img src='image.gif'> </a>`

Then if you redirect me to /page/#img3, the view will render scrolled down to img3.